# Use JQuery to move an item to lists depending on radio button selected

Tags: jquery

I have a list with items. I want the user to choose a list to add the items using a radio button to select the list.

I know php and that kind of jazz, but I'm a jquery neophyte. I scraped together some code I found, but I don't know how to make the move rely on the radio button.

If someone knows how to do it, that's awesome. If someone knows where I should look to figure it myself that is awesome too. Not afraid of learning, just don't know where to begin.

Comment: doh. Forgot the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cWHR7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tymeJV answer is correct but a simpler UI option (less clicks) is to just have two buttons:

```
<button class="move" value="#lista">Move to list A</button>
<button class="move" value="#listb">Move to list B</button>
```

And the click handler:

```
$('body').on('click', '.move', function() {
    var list = $(this).val();
    $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo(list);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is more efficient. Wonderful! Thanks for answering even after the answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I added some logic to your code. I disabled the multi-select until a radio choice was selected, and then based on the selection used a variable assigned a ternary condition to assign the correct list to append to:

Fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/cWHR7/3/

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
        //Get the right list to append to
        var list = $(":radio:checked").val() == 1 ? $("#lista") : $("#listb");

        //Append away!
        $(this).remove().appendTo(list);
    });
});

//Enable the list
$(":radio").change(function() {
    $("#list1").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Edit: You also had duplicate ID's for your lists that were being appended to, so I changed them to `lista` and `listb`

Comment: You're answer was outstanding, the only fault was that you answered it exactly... so clearly the blame here is on me. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!